# Find a point on a perpendicular line a given distance from another point?

Tags: trigonometry, recreational-mathematics, linear-programming, quadratics

I have a line from $(x_{1}, y_{1})$ to $(x_{2}, y_{2})$. I need to find two more points $(x_{3}, y_{3})$ and $(x_{4}, y_{4})$ which are a known distance (d) from one of the endpoints of my line, at a $90\, ^{\circ}$degree angle. See image:

[Here is the image to illustrate what I am describing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5jS0.png)

I can't work out a good way to do this. I considered some trig functions, or some way of using the other line with slope$ -\frac{1}{m}$, but am generally terrible at math. Vector solutions from other threads only confused me; I have and need the points in $(x, y)$ format. Head me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let:
$$
m = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}
$$
Then by taking negative reciprocals and using the point-slope formula, the equation of the perpendicular line is:
$$
y - y_2 = -\frac{1}{m}(x - x_2)
$$
We want to find the two intersection points that this line makes with the circle centred at $(x_2, y_2)$ with radius $d$:
$$
(x - x_2)^2 + (y - y_2)^2 = d^2
$$
Plugging the equation of the line into the equation of the circle yields:
\begin{align*}
(x - x_2)^2 + (-\tfrac{1}{m}(x - x_2))^2 &= d^2 \\
(x - x_2)^2 + \tfrac{1}{m^2}(x - x_2)^2 &= d^2 \\
(1 + \tfrac{1}{m^2})(x - x_2)^2 &= d^2 \\
(x - x_2)^2 &= \frac{d^2}{1 + \frac{1}{m^2}} \\
x - x_2 &= \pm \sqrt{\frac{d^2}{1 + \frac{1}{m^2}}} \\
x &= x_2 \pm \sqrt{\frac{d^2}{1 + \frac{1}{m^2}}} \\
\end{align*}
Finally, to get their corresponding $y$ coordinates, simply plug each of these two $x$ coordinates back into the equation of the line and solve for $y$.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting Rohan, and I believe you, Adriano, are a hero. This is quite clear, and makes me want to study some maths (who knows where I would begin?). I'm not sure what happened in preparation to divide by that expression on the fourth line, but thanks so much, implementation should be a breeze.